# "Key_load_pubic: Invalid Format"

Tags: ssh, ansible, terraform, cloud-init, infrastructure-as-code

Experimenting with Terraform and Ansible deployment. I have a TF template that stands up a VPC and ec2 instances in AWS, and uses cloud-init scripts to prepare the instances. I've tried to upload my own SSH keys from Puttygen in the cloud-init scripts but I am receiving a "key_load_public: invalid format" error when testing Ansible. My cloud init is as follows:

```
#Add Users
users:
  - name: ansadmin
    sudo: ["ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"]
    groups: [ sudo ]
    homedir: /home/ansadmin
    shell: /bin/bash
    passwd: $6$UwvMBQ9VAUiKDcx$/kIbPH2GxwBbpevZEJtIyjXZIW7KJgth3MXEmxhqNH.TH2yonVMz2Ob7ROD7jGKCagF3iYkYVBnkL.okPkP/d0
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCe5RaiG1mJ6QxN318GGY1ecihS61R0WssUceOnvetVeQmMdyn/H5+BFedb+RfNZwqWs0Bnj4i6fY9EDg7ylR5damZMMH+YZD4bkTkzwbjWiFudlWZYcGKorvg8mXUoI0tE9gJOtbTS2sv7M0jG3YnqEc3zY9sDTPxyjSWHXLnjF505Zk61rvXnc5fRkUKrSdrvzl3I+0kCWZ0dpQ0PSrDSVEiNR/5f5HhCaq2a16i7kW28amzdcUduX4h8/wwt83b+YxK9kV73LGsPTyB79LHVCL9QUt4ktnqU/yHQ2ZJwlsJtOIZRc5L2aPZBc+8OuEN/i5H28TbyBF1mvFezjfXt

ssh_keys:
    rsa_private: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAvV1UuXGnfWvoxoameuCuoUx1yPUeZeORovbzge0SpFctBs0k
      Nqp37h8CG8wFADPXxK3xAMDunrY+HVPzQaVDeRlDIF5sRtb0vHS3NN9M6jmQb6W1
      l/O3O1Brrp6oIEUxb1JOgCqHMw+48VFOmcdpvGZ4hf7a8w+OUK6XUGhC1A/nv6Dx
      4Icv+KhX5OwxrytN7oCyHdQiQpPfB8fMtX31+lE1YBvwtcSJaNc/dOP9ONTYXPwe
      fJYenapMTzewl1q+OkImf8DTgz9gmBMxydZdrwutOFrxpzkcVX0KITIyH1r0hTzY
      1LEG1z/8qhxijfu49lYZ2YvB2TnlbiCN/9O6+QIDAQABAoIBADbvzbWjIGlFlhmK
      VOAPMPqAmSc83Z3HoKe7pzeJVMAyvlBb0Wa+m96MRmtUDBtb7vwTTnjegBuxWWHe
      yhLAZEvMpWnNmvIOSKAn6ELBianmG14YoA8+WGkv0p2tT69VA5t9MGMEc4a/x/LS
      mNAKR0WuIMcXAeREHhCQJjvgk4q7trbOrKYgKxJsMRFwJXhYW95ZJSXjKuAVj8se
      0B5BnVWTFj3cxhgf7DVVuXrb83zIBK+6Ucq4X+nMGy8pLBw+jmcgb/Y3ssXxnh6b
      uijvUuc/i4yI9R4OwfV5tkpMFsbh2y74OS2UDfCtYCwiKjOGKEfv1oukfDSlCaqs
      2DjgacUCgYEA4/DOCfJVGWmVGsVxsJjg5k8nt/6FdJ4zx7jkvFjZ7UB6QfCmznLs
      3BRkX1ZrurRazMYNq56FXT8K6JPHsttwSy6zj/KYRRFhdEUo6EHJSELVZZHr9qIk
      duE0Fz+9FddY2jno8jyxA1+tTYudV2lkp1cVVb/UvGQCXSadmJrt+x8CgYEA1Kzc
      eRtpbKf+jPxYylqm7gPp3I3K5CgGa1gdjOTS8yc/DBbqPCQkrQe6pMKAaiWjwHz4
      y77yYmp1JtsPip7kEm2pSXVfDBmdj+aVBRUm+mDa/lXC1BgG3zaz8MsnuqoMR+19
      BO6PXN/yAEau5EnlNK6rD8A3VvvHDzXu/EPHnucCgYEAgLOa4qrdufePpQoO43Ou
      qNvQxWcE24/oFMElBeP1SKy7WzgSN0dUzf8FnX8iXM0w56Z8WYasLrZF5oRqoWad
      xRWddY24xGbH6+qQ6nMav55c93ipDx0GEcmeq/HlRcvN84n3Ka9zE0CWjc5jDNQJ
      bSMSfNRPvf+KBiajnWL9NGkCgYA2d06/dVW6jguS782NhUnbCwWJhoa/h8CdHSP0
      QWYE/7gV0IiMfnUmGyShrW5VwO3/DgJpq61Hpxv5p4CDb83ZKlyAg56j6qt/fv4L
      Hy+sT8HGARC0YLLh15CdymmSVJpwkVHDQZVVo8TGbVO9A2+/3jvQ/NkvXavNKXLb
      CEDHYQKBgQDJczoRCSmIQnloCFonNmCaWIGC7/dAjHU6VeNpbxyUGVqTiMBhG7Mk
      XIR454e1RYrielxGlPJZYRmIcK1SmI0sb/obkqbr7qLxrIMrcFqHQLatLlu6rd2K
      Url/rg6af1DzvYIrMGop4vbIZhBPeP0iyB9GGxIyE+Hh9VTU1MYEYQ==
      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

    rsa_public: ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCe5RaiG1mJ6QxN318GGY1ecihS61R0WssUceOnvetVeQmMdyn/H5+BFedb+RfNZwqWs0Bnj4i6fY9EDg7ylR5damZMMH+YZD4bkTkzwbjWiFudlWZYcGKorvg8mXUoI0tE9gJOtbTS2sv7M0jG3YnqEc3zY9sDTPxyjSWHXLnjF505Zk61rvXnc5fRkUKrSdrvzl3I+0kCWZ0dpQ0PSrDSVEiNR/5f5HhCaq2a16i7kW28amzdcUduX4h8/wwt83b+YxK9kV73LGsPTyB79LHVCL9QUt4ktnqU/yHQ2ZJwlsJtOIZRc5L2aPZBc+8OuEN/i5H28TbyBF1mvFezjfXt

write_files:
  - content: |
      ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCe5RaiG1mJ6QxN318GGY1ecihS
      61R0WssUceOnvetVeQmMdyn/H5+BFedb+RfNZwqWs0Bnj4i6fY9EDg7ylR5damZM
      MH+YZD4bkTkzwbjWiFudlWZYcGKorvg8mXUoI0tE9gJOtbTS2sv7M0jG3YnqEc3z
      Y9sDTPxyjSWHXLnjF505Zk61rvXnc5fRkUKrSdrvzl3I+0kCWZ0dpQ0PSrDSVEiN
      R/5f5HhCaq2a16i7kW28amzdcUduX4h8/wwt83b+YxK9kV73LGsPTyB79LHVCL9Q
      Ut4ktnqU/yHQ2ZJwlsJtOIZRc5L2aPZBc+8OuEN/i5H28TbyBF1mvFezjfXt
    path: /home/ansadmin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
    permissions: '0600'
    owner: ansadmin:ansadmin
    defer: true
  - content: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAvV1UuXGnfWvoxoameuCuoUx1yPUeZeORovbzge0SpFctBs0k
      Nqp37h8CG8wFADPXxK3xAMDunrY+HVPzQaVDeRlDIF5sRtb0vHS3NN9M6jmQb6W1
      l/O3O1Brrp6oIEUxb1JOgCqHMw+48VFOmcdpvGZ4hf7a8w+OUK6XUGhC1A/nv6Dx
      4Icv+KhX5OwxrytN7oCyHdQiQpPfB8fMtX31+lE1YBvwtcSJaNc/dOP9ONTYXPwe
      fJYenapMTzewl1q+OkImf8DTgz9gmBMxydZdrwutOFrxpzkcVX0KITIyH1r0hTzY
      1LEG1z/8qhxijfu49lYZ2YvB2TnlbiCN/9O6+QIDAQABAoIBADbvzbWjIGlFlhmK
      VOAPMPqAmSc83Z3HoKe7pzeJVMAyvlBb0Wa+m96MRmtUDBtb7vwTTnjegBuxWWHe
      yhLAZEvMpWnNmvIOSKAn6ELBianmG14YoA8+WGkv0p2tT69VA5t9MGMEc4a/x/LS
      mNAKR0WuIMcXAeREHhCQJjvgk4q7trbOrKYgKxJsMRFwJXhYW95ZJSXjKuAVj8se
      0B5BnVWTFj3cxhgf7DVVuXrb83zIBK+6Ucq4X+nMGy8pLBw+jmcgb/Y3ssXxnh6b
      uijvUuc/i4yI9R4OwfV5tkpMFsbh2y74OS2UDfCtYCwiKjOGKEfv1oukfDSlCaqs
      2DjgacUCgYEA4/DOCfJVGWmVGsVxsJjg5k8nt/6FdJ4zx7jkvFjZ7UB6QfCmznLs
      3BRkX1ZrurRazMYNq56FXT8K6JPHsttwSy6zj/KYRRFhdEUo6EHJSELVZZHr9qIk
      duE0Fz+9FddY2jno8jyxA1+tTYudV2lkp1cVVb/UvGQCXSadmJrt+x8CgYEA1Kzc
      eRtpbKf+jPxYylqm7gPp3I3K5CgGa1gdjOTS8yc/DBbqPCQkrQe6pMKAaiWjwHz4
      y77yYmp1JtsPip7kEm2pSXVfDBmdj+aVBRUm+mDa/lXC1BgG3zaz8MsnuqoMR+19
      BO6PXN/yAEau5EnlNK6rD8A3VvvHDzXu/EPHnucCgYEAgLOa4qrdufePpQoO43Ou
      qNvQxWcE24/oFMElBeP1SKy7WzgSN0dUzf8FnX8iXM0w56Z8WYasLrZF5oRqoWad
      xRWddY24xGbH6+qQ6nMav55c93ipDx0GEcmeq/HlRcvN84n3Ka9zE0CWjc5jDNQJ
      bSMSfNRPvf+KBiajnWL9NGkCgYA2d06/dVW6jguS782NhUnbCwWJhoa/h8CdHSP0
      QWYE/7gV0IiMfnUmGyShrW5VwO3/DgJpq61Hpxv5p4CDb83ZKlyAg56j6qt/fv4L
      Hy+sT8HGARC0YLLh15CdymmSVJpwkVHDQZVVo8TGbVO9A2+/3jvQ/NkvXavNKXLb
      CEDHYQKBgQDJczoRCSmIQnloCFonNmCaWIGC7/dAjHU6VeNpbxyUGVqTiMBhG7Mk
      XIR454e1RYrielxGlPJZYRmIcK1SmI0sb/obkqbr7qLxrIMrcFqHQLatLlu6rd2K
      Url/rg6af1DzvYIrMGop4vbIZhBPeP0iyB9GGxIyE+Hh9VTU1MYEYQ==
      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    path: /home/ansadmin/.ssh/id_rsa
    permissions: '0600'
    owner: ansadmin:ansadmin
    defer: true
  - content: |
      ansadmin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
    path: /etc/sudoers
    append: true
```

If I replace the key using "ssh-keygen", I can use "ssh-copy-id" to the client node with no errors - so I presume something must be wrong with my format coming from Puttygen. The literal format - how the Puttygen public key is laid out in id_rsa.pub - looks exactly the same as the key produced by ssh-keygen. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on my own by just copying a key directly from ssh-keygen instead. Not sure why the Puttygen key didn't work, but whatever works!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have no idea what the answer is. All I know is that it worked after copying the key from ssh-keygen instead of Puttygen. If anyone knows how to explain the solution, please let us know!